# This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file

Tags: android-studio

After I installed the API 27 and created an AVD for that API, my projects runs fine. But if I try to test on an AVD with API 18, I got the error message:

> emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.

I'm using Android Studio 3.4.1. I've already tried everything. Installed all the tools for API 27. I also got the error:

> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined.

I've tried to set the system variable to the following path

```
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

but it didn't work. I saw a lot of questions about this error, but none of them solved my problem.